# Batch Insert with JTA (EntityManager cannot use getTransaction)

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-data, batch-processing, entitymanager

I'm working in a project with spring data and apache camel, we have 2 databases, Sql Server and Oracle with JTA. The problem arises because I need to insert data from a large file (about 10000000 records), so I decided to do using batch insert as:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="persistenceUnitSql")
EntityManager em;

public void insertBatch() {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
      Point point = new Point(i, i);
      em.persist(point);
      if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
          em.getTransaction().commit();
          em.clear();          
          em.getTransaction().begin();
      }
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

but this problem happened:

```
    A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
```

Any help...

Comment: Why do you need multiple transactions? In general a `flush` followed by a `clear` is sufficient. Then simply mark the `insertBatch` method with `@Transactional` and you should be good. Or even better use Spring Batch instead of rolling your own batching solution...

Comment: We are using spring data with 2 databases, the class in charge of to do the persistence of an object extends from CrudRepository. This class has methods that insert a single record at the same time. I have to read every line from txt file using apache camel and then insert this line into database. With big files (300MB) the process the process takes a long time.

Comment: Still why roll your own whilst you could use spring batch? But as mentioned a `flush` and `clear` and a single transaction in general work. With regards of JTA in general, especially with multiple transactional resources, it is expected to use container managed transactions instead of doing your own.

Answer (score 2):

It seems much harder than expected to self-control JTA transaction.  One workaround I normally use is to have a separate "service" which do one batch of insert, and you setup REQUIRES_NEW transaction propagation policy on that method, so it looks like:

```
class FooService {

    private PointPersister pointPersister;

    @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRED)
    public void insertBatch() {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(10000);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
            points.add(new Point(i,1));
            if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
                pointPersister.insertPointBatch(points);
            }
        }
    }
}

class PointPersisterImpl implements PointPersister {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)    // in a separate txn
    public void insertPointBatch(List<Point> points) {
        // persist points
    }
}
```

There are also other choices you can make to avoid dealing with the troublesome and error-prone manual transaction handling.  [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/) is one of the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to solve this in the following way:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="persistenceUnitSql") 
// from persistence xml <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitSql" transaction-type="JTA"> 
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Autowired
private JtaTransactionManager transactionManagerSqlServer;
// from application-context.xml
//<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManagerSqlServer" />

public List<Point> insertBatch(List<Point> datos) {

    try {
        UserTransaction transaction = transactionManagerSqlServer.getUserTransaction();     
        transaction.begin();
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        for (Point punto : datos) {
            em.persist(punto);
        }
        transaction.commit();
        em.close();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }       

    return datos;
}
```